# Can RequireJs and Closure play together on Play 2.1?

Tags: playframework, requirejs, playframework-2.1, google-closure

I've migrated a portion of our codebase recently to use RequireJs on PlayFramework.

Unfortunately, I discovered that this broke all of of our old, non-migrated code as the standard Closure compile and minification pipeline (turning files from file.js to file.min.js) seems to get turned off the moment you specify play to use the RequireJs optimiser.

Is there a way for the two to play nicely with each other? Ideally I would like the Closure compiler to still generate its own .min.js files in the classic way so our old codebase's hardcoded script references don't break: 
i.e.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/script.min.js")"></script>
```

Should work, whereas with the requireJs compiler there would not be a script.min.js, and instead a javascripts-min/script.js in prod and a javascripts/script.js in dev (causing problems with our legacy code).